# ProgressDialog in AsyncTask only displayed at the end of the task for a short time

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a `AsyncTask<Client, Void, Boolean>` called `LoginTask` with a `ProgressDialog`, which you can see here.
Now my problem is, if I launch this task with `LoginTask(...).execute().get()` the `ProgressDialog` is only shown very short at the end of the `AsyncTask`. Also I've put in some `Thread.sleep()`, but if I do that, I also get a `ProgressDialog` at the end of the Thread.

How can the ProgressDialog be displayed the whole async task?

```
    public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Client, Void, Boolean>
    {
      private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
      private MainActivity activity;

      public LoginTask(MainActivity activity)
      {
    this.activity = activity;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage(activity.getText(R.string.asynctask_login_connect));
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
  }

  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(Client... params)
  {
    try
    {
      Client client = params[0];
      if (client.connect())
      {
        progressDialog.setMessage(activity.getText(R.string.asynctask_login));
        if (client.manageHandshake())
        {
          return true;
        }
        else
          return false;
      }
      else
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      Log.e(LoginTask.class.getSimpleName(), "Can not handshake and connect to/with server.", e);
      return false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
  {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
  }

}
```

Comment: why you are calling get method? use onPostExecute to get results from doInBackground will show progressDialog until doInBackground not complete

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I don't understand exactly. I get the result int the onPostExecute, but what to do then? Can you give me an example please?

Comment: start AsyncTask `LoginTask(...).execute()` instead of `LoginTask(...).execute().get()` and move code which you want to execute after getting result from server in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs of the get(),

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

This means that it will block the calling `Thread` until the execution is done; this defeats the whole purpose of using `AsyncTask`. Just call `execute()` and update the UI `Thread` from `onPostExecute()`